# problem with counterCache of cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have in a video sharing website project these models :

```
 class Video extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'Video';
        var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Tag' => array(
                'className' => 'Tag',
                'joinTable' => 'videos_tags',
                'foreignKey' => 'video_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
                'unique' => true,
            )
        );
    }

    class Tag extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'Tag';

        var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Video' => array(
                'className' => 'Video',
                'joinTable' => 'videos_tags',
                'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'video_id',
                'unique' => true,
            )
        );

    }



 class VideosTag extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'VideosTag';

        var $belongsTo = array(
            'Video' => array(
                'className' => 'Video',
                'foreignKey' => 'video_id',
            ),
            'Tag' => array(
                'className' => 'Tag',
                'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'counterCache' => 'videos_tag_counter'
            )
        );
    }
```

The counterCache for tags is not working. I don't know why and when I tried to add a beforeSave() callback to videosTag model I found that it doesn't execute when a video get saved (and this video has tags and i find them in the database so how the relation videosTags is saved ? ) !!! can any body explain why this is happening.

Comment: How are you saving the data? The `VideosTag` models `beforeSave` would only be triggered if you save the record using the `VideosTag` model, but probably not via `$this->Tag->saveAll`.

Comment: I don't know how it is saved because cakePHP generated every thing and because the Video model has a HABTM relation with tags the videosTags get saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving a Video with data like this:

```
array(
  'Video' => array(
    ...
  ),
  'Tag' => array(
    'Tag' => array(
      ...
    ),
  ),
);
```

on the Video model will not trigger a beforeSave callback on the VideosTag model because Cake handles HABTM data without requiring (or even using) the join/with/through model.

There is no built in functionality for what you are trying to achieve, as far as I am aware.

Check out [Counter Cache behavior for HABTM relations](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/counter-cache-behavior-for-habtm-relations), might do what you need